# When I execute playbook, getting the following error

Tags: ansible

I get the following error when I run my playbook in ansible below:

> The error appears to be in
>   '/home/ec2-user/ansible/playbooks/tasks/rhel7_amigen.yml':  line 39,
>   column 7, but maybe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
roles:
    - sws.rhel7_amigen

          ^ here
```

Comment: `sws.rhel7_amigen` this is your role? Can you show us the playbook as well?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this if `sws.rhel7_amigen` is your role:

```
roles: 
  - { role: sws.rhel7_amigen }
```